# How Finalizer work for CustomResouce object?

Tags: kubernetes, operator-sdk

In Kubernetes and Operator-sdk, we can define CRD (Custom Resource Definition) and CR (Custom Resource). In my operator controller, when a CR is initialized, then the controller reconcillation create a new Deployment and service.

When we delete a CR object, then the associated resources (such as Deployment or service) will be deleted as well at the same time. I understand it should be done by CR Finalizer. But, in Operator-SDK and my controller code, I never see any code to register or add Finalizer for CR, is there any default behavior for Operator-Sdk?

Could anybody point how it work for the case - "while deleting CR, the associated Deployment and Service have deleted as well"? Which part in controller is responsible for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deletion of associated resources is not part of a controller. It's done by Kubernetes's [garbage collector](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/garbage-collection/).

Basically, garbage collector using [OwnerReference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.19/#ownerreference-v1-meta) objects to find orphaned resources and delete them. Most likely, you set `OwnerReference` by calling [`controllerutil.SetControllerReference`](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/controller-runtime/blob/74fd294a89c65c8efc17ab92e0d2014d36e357a8/pkg/controller/controllerutil/controllerutil.go#L59) method somewhere in your code.